# VBA Tree View from string

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I would like to get tree view using excel vba.I have many String likes this

```
      /folderOne/fileOne
      /folderTwo/fileThree
      /folderOne/fileTwo
      /folderThree/fileFour
      /folderTwo/subFolderTwo
      /folderThree/subFolderThree/fileFive
```

and I would like to make tree veiw in excel sheet using vba.My requirement is

```
     folderOne
         L fileOne
         L fileTwo
     folderTwo
         L fileThree
     folderThree
         L fileFour
         subFolderThree
               L fileFive
```

So how should I define it?Please share me some ideas or links.I'm very new to vba.

Comment: you want your tree in one column? or in different columns?

Comment: @L42 different columns

Comment: Test it now. I have updated my answer post your recent edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Further to the recent edit, let's say your worksheet looks like this. Note that I created some dummy samples to demonstrate duplicate sub folders.

```
/branches/test
/branches/test/link.txt
/branches/test/Test1/link.txt
/branches/testOne
/tags
/trunk
/trunk/test/Test1/link.txt
/trunk/testing
/trunk/testing/link.txt
/trunk/testOne
```

[image]

Paste the below code in a module and run it. The output will be generated in a new sheet.

[image]

**CODE**:

```
Option Explicit

Const MyDelim As String = "#Sidz#"

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim MyAr As Variant, TempAr As Variant
    Dim LRow As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, r As Long, Level As Long
    Dim delRange As Range
    Dim sFormula As String, stemp1 As String, stemp2 As String

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '~~> Set this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ws.Columns(1).Sort Key1:=ws.Range("A1"), _
    Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, _
    MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    LRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    MyAr = ws.Range("A1:A" & LRow).Value

    Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

    r = 1: k = 2

    With wsNew
        For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
            TempAr = Split(MyAr(i, 1), "/")
            Level = UBound(TempAr) - 1
            .Range("A" & r).Value = TempAr(1)

            For j = 1 To Level
                r = r + 1
                .Cells(r, k).Value = Split(MyAr(i, 1), "/")(j + 1)
                k = k + 1
            Next j
            r = r + 1
            k = 2
        Next

        LRow = LastRow(wsNew)
        lCol = LastColumn(wsNew)

        For i = LRow To 1 Step -1
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, lCol))) = 0 And _
               Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(1), .Cells(i, 1)) > 1 Then
                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i

        LRow = LastRow(wsNew)

        For i = 2 To LRow
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "" And .Cells(i - 1, 1).Value <> "" Then _
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = .Cells(i - 1, 1).Value
        Next i

        For i = 2 To LRow
            For j = 2 To (lCol - 1)
                If .Cells(i, j).Value = "" And .Cells(i - 1, j).Value <> "" And _
                .Cells(i, j - 1).Value = .Cells(i - 1, j - 1).Value Then _
                .Cells(i, j).Value = .Cells(i - 1, j).Value
            Next j
        Next i

        lCol = LastColumn(wsNew) + 1

        For i = 1 To LRow
            sFormula = ""
            For j = 1 To (lCol - 1)
                sFormula = sFormula & "," & .Cells(i, j).Address
            Next j
            .Cells(i, lCol).Formula = "=Concatenate(" & Mid(sFormula, 2) & ")"
        Next i

        .Columns(lCol).Value = .Columns(lCol).Value

        For i = LRow To 2 Step -1
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(lCol), .Cells(i, lCol)) > 1 Then
                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i

        .Columns(lCol).Delete
        lCol = LastColumn(wsNew) + 1
        LRow = LastRow(wsNew)

        For i = LRow To 2 Step -1
            For j = lCol To 2 Step -1
                If .Cells(i, j).Value <> "" And .Cells(i, j).Value = .Cells(i - 1, j).Value Then
                    For k = 2 To (j - 1)
                        stemp1 = stemp1 & MyDelim & .Cells(i, k).Value
                        stemp2 = stemp2 & MyDelim & .Cells(i - 1, k).Value
                    Next k
                    stemp1 = Mid(stemp1, Len(MyDelim) + 1)
                    stemp2 = Mid(stemp2, Len(MyDelim) + 1)

                    If UCase(stemp1) = UCase(stemp2) Then
                        .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, k)).ClearContents
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        Next i


        For i = LRow To 2 Step -1
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(1), _
            .Cells(i, 1).Value) > 1 Then .Cells(i, 1).ClearContents
        Next i

        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub

Function LastRow(wks As Worksheet) As Long
    LastRow = wks.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=wks.Range("A1"), _
                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row
End Function

Function LastColumn(wks As Worksheet) As Long
    LastColumn = wks.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=wks.Range("A1"), _
                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Column
End Function
```

**Disclaimer**: I have not done any checks for `/`. Please either ensure that the data has `/` or put an extra line to check for `/` using `Instr` else you will get an error when you run the code.

Comment: +1 Impressive. You might want to add Application.Screenupdating=False/True for a faster flow of the code and maybe a check for "/" if it exists before splitting?

Comment: @PradeepKumar: Good points :) I added the ScreenUpdating Part. Regarding the check for `/`, added a disclaimer :p

Comment: +1 Good solution Siddharth. Aesthetically, you may look to add the tree outlines. :-)

Comment: @PankajJaju: Thanks :) Yeah I had thought of adding `grouping` but then I was too lazy to do it :p

Comment: @SiddharthRout - You need to add `LastRow` and `LastColumn` functions code too.

Comment: @PankajJaju: I had it there but after making the edits pradeep suggested, I forgot to put it back :p

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks for solution.You got your bounty next 6 hours :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout what do you do when rows are categorized. e.g.   /folderOne/fileOne/,folderTwo/fileThree,/folderOne/fileTwo,/folderThree/fileFour,/folderOne/fileThree,/folderThree/subFolderThree/fileFive

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye: You mean everything in 1 row?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. One way i can think of in such a case is to sort the data manually and then apply the code given above.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I mean parent folders have no order likes /folderOne/...                                                        /folderTwo/...                                                         /folderOne/...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46494/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-sai-ye-yan-naing-aye)

Answer (score 2):

ok assuming your data is in Column A, try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address)

rng.TextToColumns rng.Range("A1"), , , , , , , , True, "/"

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1", _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address)

For Each cel In rng
    If cel.Row <> 1 Then If cel.Value = cel.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then cel.ClearContents
Next

End Sub
```

Hope this get's you started somehow.

Comment: + 1 Nicely done but needs more trimming :) The code will fail if there is one more line say `/folderThree/subFolderThree/fileSix` after say `/folderThree/subFolderThree/fileFive` but then like you said this will get OP started :)

Comment: [ANOTHER](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?583663-RESOLVED-Complication-with-Treeview) interesting way to do it :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout hahaha while i was testing, i thought of that as well. and also, i don't know if the OP like the tree that way. I mean the way it was illustrated was someting else. Like how a `Pivot` summarizes data. or how you arrange it in your post LOL.

Comment: @L42 i don't understand your answer.so please let me explain more details

Answer (score 2):

Here is something from me.

Though you will still have to do some work yourself, which you can do easily.
Assuming that your file paths are in "A" column. You will have to change the code appropriately to suit your needs. In my code, I have just hardcoded which cells to pickup to show in treeview. You will need to modify according to your needs.

**DISCLAIMER:**

The solution provided below is intended only for personal use. This solution is not feasible in case you are planning to distribute your Excel file. Also, your PC should have comctl32.ocx registered (which should be if you have VB6 runtime installed)

**Steps:**

1. Put your data in "A" column. (to test my code. modify later as per your need)
   [image]
2. Goto `Developer` tab, and click `Design Mode`. Then click the `Insert` button on toolbar. 
   [image]
3. Click the `more...` icon. The one in the bottom right corner. This will open `More Controls` dialog.
4. Look for `Microsoft TreeView Control, Version 6`. Select that and click OK.
   [image]
5. A TreeView Control will be added to the sheet. Double click that and it will open the code window.

Paste the following code in code window.

(Replace `TreeView31` in the code with the name of your TreeView control.)

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    LoadTreeView TreeView31
End Sub

Sub Button2_Click()
    TreeView31.Nodes.Clear
End Sub

Sub LoadTreeView(TV As TreeView)
    Dim i As Integer, RootNode As Node
    TV.Nodes.Clear
    Set RootNode = TV.Nodes.Add(, , "ROOT", "ROOT")
    RootNode.Expanded = True
    For i = 1 To 5
        AddNode TV, RootNode, Cells(i, 1)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub AddNode(TV As TreeView, RootNode As Node, Path As String)
    Dim ParentNode As Node, NodeKey As String
    Dim PathNodes() As String

    On Error GoTo ErrH
    PathNodes = Split(Path, "/")
    NodeKey = RootNode.Key
    For i = 1 To UBound(PathNodes)
        Set ParentNode = TV.Nodes(NodeKey)
        NodeKey = NodeKey & "/" & PathNodes(i)
        TV.Nodes.Add ParentNode, tvwChild, NodeKey, PathNodes(i)
        ParentNode.Expanded = True
    Next

    Exit Sub
ErrH:
    If Err.Number = 35601 Then
        Set ParentNode = RootNode
        Resume
    End If
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

**6.** On Developers tab, click the `Insert` button on toolbar again and add a `Button` control (the one in the top left corner). Add it to your sheet, and it will automatically popup `Assign Macro` dialog. Select `Sheet1.Button1_Click` from the list. And rename the caption to `Fill TreeView` (or whatever you think appropriate for you).
[image]

**7.** Add another button. This time bind it with `Sheet1.Button2_Click` and set its caption to `Clear`

**8.** Click the `Design Mode` button on toolbar again to turn it off.

**9.** Now click the `Fill TreeView` and it should fill your filenames in the TreeView.
[image]

Comment: Pradeep, I have already suggested a Treeview version :) See the comments under L42's post. Also Treeview is not a free control ;)

Answer (score 2):

Was looking for something with a hierarchy to try out some recursive stuff. Here is my solution for this question:

```
Sub callTheFunction()
    '"A1:A6" = range with the values, "A10" = first cell of target range, "/" = delimiter
    Call createHierarchy(Range("A1:A6"), Range("A10"), "/")
End Sub

Sub createHierarchy(rngSource As Range, rngTarget As Range, strDelimiter As String)
    Dim dic As Object, rng As Range
    Set dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each rng In rngSource
        addValuesToDic dic, Split(rng.Value, strDelimiter), 1
    Next
    writeKeysToRange dic, rngTarget, 0, 0
End Sub

Sub addValuesToDic(ByRef dic As Object, ByVal avarValues As Variant, i As Long)
    If Not dic.Exists(avarValues(i)) Then
        Set dic(avarValues(i)) = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    End If
    If i < UBound(avarValues) Then addValuesToDic dic(avarValues(i)), avarValues, i + 1
End Sub

Sub writeKeysToRange(dic As Object, rngTarget As Range, _
ByRef lngRowOffset As Long, ByVal lngColOffset As Long)
    Dim varKey As Variant
    For Each varKey In dic.keys
        'adds "L    " in front of file if value is like "file*"
        rngTarget.Offset(lngRowOffset, lngColOffset) = IIf(varKey Like "file*", "L    " & varKey, varKey)
        lngRowOffset = lngRowOffset + 1
        If dic(varKey).Count > 0 Then
            writeKeysToRange dic(varKey), rngTarget, lngRowOffset, lngColOffset + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```