# Make folders and files using excel vba macro and display with tree view and hyperlinks

Tags: excel, treeview, vba

I would like to make folder and file by reading the following paths

```
       /project/tags/folder2/command.txt
       /project/branches/folder1/folder1.1/Notes.docx
```

and construct folders and files under drive D:\ likes this

```
      project
          tags
              folder2
                   command.txt
          branches
              folder1
                    folder1.1
                           Notes.docx
```

.Then use this physical structure to type tree view with hyperlinks(Please assume I mark * for the names that words have hyperlinks) at last files and folders in excel sheet using vba macro.See

```
      project
         |_tags
         |   |_folder2*
         |         |_command.txt*
         |_branches
         |     |_folder1
         |           |_folder1.1*
         |                 |_Notes.docx*
```

So please help something for vba noob.

Comment: Do you have some code already?

Comment: Didn't you asked [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396253/vba-tree-view-from-string/)?

Comment: @PankajJaju not similar, read my question carefully.according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396253/vba-tree-view-from-string/ I would like to add hyperlinks to last file and folder(marked with star)that's my problem.

Comment: Have you looked at my solution below?

Comment: Your question is too broad. You should learn VBA instead of asking other people to do your work for you. http://whathaveyoutried.com/ Then come back here when something specific is causing you a problem and you can't find the answer.

Comment: Hello! Is the code below working okay for you? Let me know if it can be improved.

Comment: @Taosique Sorry for late replied.It is not OK for me.I only need last folder and file(marked with stars) to add hyperlinks.Your code contain hyperlinks in each level.But 1+ for your idea.

Comment: Okay, modified it. Now it will highlight only end-node folders: empty folders and folders with files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that should do the trick.
This macro will take folder path from cell `A1` and list recursively its contents and subfolder contents with hyperlinks.
**Update:** fixed, now it's working. :)

```
Public Position As Integer
Public Indent As Integer

Sub ListFileTree()

Position = 0
Indent = 0

Call RecurseFolderList(Range("A1").Value)

End Sub

Private Sub ClearFormatting(Rng As Range)

    Rng.Formula = Rng.Value2
    Rng.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    Rng.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone

End Sub

Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal strPath As String) As String
    If Right$(strPath, 1) <> "\" And Len(strPath) > 0 Then
        GetFilenameFromPath = GetFilenameFromPath(Left$(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)) + Right$(strPath, 1)
    End If
End Function

Function RecurseFolderList(FolderName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim FSO, NextFolder, FolderArray, FileArray, NextFile
    Dim OriginalRange As Range
    Dim RemoveHyperlink As Boolean
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        RecurseFolderList = False
    Exit Function

    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
    If FSO.FolderExists(FolderName) Then

        Set NextFolder = FSO.GetFolder(FolderName)
        Set FolderArray = NextFolder.SubFolders
        Set FileArray = NextFolder.Files

        RemoveHyperlink = False
        Set OriginalRange = Range("A2").Offset(Position - 1, Indent)

        Indent = Indent + 1

        For Each NextFolder In FolderArray

            Range("A2").Offset(Position, Indent).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & NextFile & """,""" & UCase(GetFilenameFromPath(NextFolder)) & """)"
            Position = Position + 1

            RecurseFolderList (NextFolder)

            RemoveHyperlink = True
        Next

        For Each NextFile In FileArray

            Range("A2").Offset(Position, Indent).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & NextFile & """,""" & GetFilenameFromPath(NextFile) & """)"
            Position = Position + 1

            RemoveHyperlink = False

            DoEvents
        Next

        If RemoveHyperlink Then
            Call ClearFormatting(OriginalRange)
        End If

        Set NextFolder = Nothing
        Set FolderArray = Nothing
        Set FileArray = Nothing
        Set NextFile = Nothing

    Else
        RecurseFolderList = False
    End If

    Set FSO = Nothing
    Indent = Indent - 1

End Function
```