# VBA script to create dir and file

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create directory folders and files using excel VBA script. I have the following String

```
          /path/project/command.exe
```

And I create folders and file under drive `D:\` likes this `D:\path\project\command.exe`.My file may be vary .exe or .txt or .doc or etc.. I already used `MkDir` but I only create folder not create file. So help me to create directory folders and files using excel VBA script. If exe file or some file types that are not create from vba, I only need to create some temporary files for replacement of exe file.

Comment: you can't *"make"* an .exe from vba

Comment: @mehow the way I see the question is that he doesn't want the VBA project as `.exe`. Only some dumb files to replace thereafter. Maybe the title should read `VBA macro create dir and file` instead

Comment: @hstay right, but why would anyone want to create an dummy exe?

Comment: @mehow I think it is related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622601/make-folders-and-files-using-excel-vba-macro-and-display-with-tree-view-and-hype

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create blank files you could use cmd's fsutil:

```
Sub createBlankFile()
    Shell "fsutil file createnew ""D:\path\project\command.exe"" 0", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

The 0 refers to the size of the file.