# For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr) Error when only 1 entry in MyAr

Tags: arrays, vba, treeview

I am stuck with the Problem described in the headline. I am populating a TreeView from strings using and adapted Version of @Siddharth Rout 's approach (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21457669/6564572). However, if I only have one entry in the respective range  I get a "Runtime Error 13 - Type mismatch". I tried manually Setting i = 1 to UBound(MyAr) and a few other things but needless to say, it did not work. If there are 2 or more entries, it runs through smoothly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet
Dim MyAr As Variant, TempAr As Variant
Dim LRow As Long, lCol As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, r As Long, Level As Long
Dim delRange As Range
Dim sFormula As String, stemp1 As String, stemp2 As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Supplier Skills")

ws.Columns(1).Sort Key1:=ws.Range("A2"), _
Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, _
MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

Dim f As Range
Dim ColumnLetter As String

Set f = ws.Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(What:=UserForm1.SESNo, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
ColumnLetter = Split(f.Address, "$")(1)

LRow = ws.Range(ColumnLetter & "30").End(xlUp).row
MyAr = ws.Range(ColumnLetter & "2:" & ColumnLetter & LRow).value

Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Selected TreeView")
wsNew.Range("A1:D30").Clear

r = 2: k = 3

With wsNew
    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)    '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<--ERROR HERE--<<<<<<<<<<<
        TempAr = Split(MyAr(i, 1), "\")
        Level = UBound(TempAr) - 1
        .Range("B" & r).value = TempAr(1)
.

.   'same as in original code

.
```

Comment: What is Lbound(MyAr) & Ubound giving you as a result in this instance?

Comment: The MyAr has the correct string, but the LBound and UBound show "Type Mismatch"

Comment: When you set `MyAr`, try dropping the `.Value` from the `Range` object statement.  Where there's only one row, it seems that `MyAr` is being set to a string rather than an array, and that could be why you get the type mismatch on the `LBound` and `UBound` statements.

Comment: Verify this with `? IsArray(MyAr)` in the `Immediate` Window of the VB Editor.  IF that's `false` then your array isn't an array.  If it's `true` then the problem's somewhere else?

Comment: @Dave Thank you for your Response. I tried that but unfortunately, it does not change the Error

Comment: On an unrelated note, you're not handling the possibility that the `Set f = ` statement fails where the `find` gets nothing; you should avoid that situation as if f is nothing you'll hit an error setting the `ColumnLetter`

Comment: The Immediate Window gives out "False"

Comment: Then `MyAr` isn't being set to an array as I suspected.  Check the value you have for `LRow` since it's used to set the range for the array?

Comment: It is not possible to run the Sub without an entry in the respective TextBox (so he cannot find nothing). Do I still need to code for this eventuality Dave?
And do you have any other idea, what the initialy question's problem could be?

Comment: LRow is found correctly as "2". There is the ID in row 1 and the one entry in row nr 2. And MyAr has the correct string from the cell for the respective ID... :/

Comment: @InternInNeed see workaround answer below when _MyAr_  results with only 1 element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only 1 item in *MyAr* it's not set-up as an array yet, so you can try the following workaround when ***MyAr*** will reslut with only 1 element:

```
If IsArray(MyAr) Then
    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        ' do your loop things here

    Next i
Else
    ' only 1 element in array

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone else wondering the same in the future, I followed Shai Rado's tip, with the following Addition:

```
If IsArray(MyAr) Then
    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        'Loops here
    Next i
Else
    Dim myElements() As String

    myElements = Split(ws.Range(ColumnLetter & "2").value, "\")

    wsNew.Range("B2") = myElements(0)
    wsNew.Range("C3") = myElements(1)
    wsNew.Range("C4") = myElements(2)

End If
```

I just declared the range where the string-parts need to be copied to manually after splitting the Array. It is easy since you should know exactly at what column/row number the extra-case will occur for each entry.