# Is there a way to put manydifferent folders into a treeview

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, treeview

I am new with vba, and I want to fill a huge "microsoft treeview control, version 6.0" with 15000 different folders in excel on this format:

```
/folderOne
/folderOne/subfolderOne
/folderOne/subfolderTwo
/folderTwo/subfolderOne
```

I have used the [Pradeep Kumar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21460909/4717755), but it makes excel crash if I try to make it with too many rows (ok with 1000 rows, but not with 2000 rows) which is as follow:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    LoadTreeView1 TreeView1, 1, 1000
End Sub


Private Sub LoadTreeView1(TV As TreeView, min As Integer, max As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer, RootNode As Node
    TV.Nodes.Clear
    Set RootNode = TV.Nodes.Add(, , "ROOT", "ROOT")
    RootNode.Expanded = True
    For i = min To max
        AddNode TV, RootNode, Cells(i, 1)
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub AddNode(TV As TreeView, RootNode As Node, Path As String)
    Dim ParentNode As Node, NodeKey As String
    Dim PathNodes() As String

    On Error GoTo ErrH
    PathNodes = Split(Path, "/")
    NodeKey = RootNode.Key
    For i = 1 To UBound(PathNodes)
        Set ParentNode = TV.Nodes(NodeKey)
        NodeKey = NodeKey & "/" & PathNodes(i)
        TV.Nodes.Add ParentNode, tvwChild, NodeKey, PathNodes(i)
        ParentNode.Expanded = True
    Next

    Exit Sub
ErrH:
    If Err.Number = 35601 Then
        Set ParentNode = RootNode
        Resume
    End If
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

My treeview looks good on excel, similar to the one below but my issue is that i can't put enough data in it.

[image]

I have exported my list into access, but the process is different, and I am a bit lost because as I said, I am new with vba.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you run your code, not populating a treeview, populating 1-10K rows in Excel, see if the code functions.  I've read in the past that treeviews use a lot of memory when creating nodes, so you may be encountering an error of that nature.

Comment: Yes sure, it worked in excel for a thousand rows, but not for 2 thousand as mentionned above if this is your question.

Answer (score 1):

Main strategy in using treeview controls is to upload data of expanded rows on demand.

- firstly, you're loading just high-level treeview elements (clienti list)
- after user clicks the node, the method of filling corresponding node with child elements is called

Idea is that nobody would ever scroll through all list of elements in treeview.

These details could be difficult if you're new in VBA, so may be it is better to use linked lists. E.g.

- list1: contains clienti list
- list2: contains dates
- after selecting element in list1, list2 recordsource is dynamically changed in order to provide list of only and only elements, that correspond to list1

This solution exceeds limitations of memory for treeview control, and suitable if you have definite depth of taxonomy of your objects.

Comment: Thank you, im gonna try to find a way to do that